# Firing a custom Google Analytics conversion event on Shopify Thank You Page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, shopify

I'm trying to fire a custom GA event on the checkout page but unable to figure it out. I've implemented the easy Shopify setup where I just add my GA account to Online Store > Preferences.

On my checkout additional scripts:

```
ga('create', 'UA-********-1', 'auto');
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Pricing Experiment',
  eventAction: 'Purchase',
  eventLabel: version,
  eventValue: '{{ total_price | money_without_currency }}'
});
```

This gives a "GA not defined error". I tried adding the GA script directly:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
    [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-********-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', {
      hitType: 'event',
      eventCategory: 'Pricing Experiment',
      eventAction: 'Purchase',
      eventLabel: version,
      eventValue: '{{ total_price | money_without_currency }}'
    });    
</script>
```

This change removes the error in the console but the event is still not firing in GA. Finally, I tried another solution I found:

```
<script>
  $(window).ready(function() {
    $('head script[async][src*="analytics"]').on('load', function() {
      ga('send', 'event', 'checkout', 'complete');
    });
  });
</script>
```

But this just gives me "$" is not defined. Tried switching for jQuery and I get "jQuery is not defined".

Where am I going wrong? How can I send a simple event???

Comment: Do you have the jQuery library loaded? Why not use native JS? If you're waiting for the `load` event to fire your checkout event, then there's a possibility that the user navigates to another page or exits the site, while the  analytics library is still loading, meaning you'd miss the checkout event altogether.

Comment: It's on the Shopify checkout page which we don't actually have access to the source code. Jquery is loaded on the rest of my site but might not be getting loaded in time for this. What would the native JS look like?